# Sort One Dictionary with Another iPhone

Tags: iphone, sorting, nsmutabledictionary

I have two NSMutableDictionary objects. Dict 1 has fewer keys than dict 2, but the keys that both dictionaries share are identical in syntax. I'd like to re-sort dict 1 by the values for those keys in dict 2. The values in Dict 2 are integers.

Can someone get me started?

EDIT:
I have one array of keys and a dictionary with keys and numerical values. There are more keys and values in the dictionary than keys/objects in the array. I would like to re-order the array by the corresponding values of those keys from the dictionary.

Sorry for the redo on the question, but this more accurate.

Comment: Hi,  I'm sorry, but this sentence doesn't make any sense: "Dict 1 has fewer keys than dict 2, but the keys that are in both are exactly the same."  Maybe a typo?

Comment: I updated the question. I meant to say that the keys they both share are identical strings, but dict 2 has keys that are not in dict 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for the method call sortedArrayUsingComparator:?  This will take one array and return you an array with the elements sorted.

Here's some sample code which sorts dictionaries based on a value in the field "sort order".  You should read the documentation on these calls:

```
    NSComparisonResult (^sortBlock)(id, id) = ^(id obj1, id obj2) {

    if ([[obj1 objectForKey:@"sortorder"] intValue] > [[obj2 objectForKey:@"sortorder"] intValue]) { 
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    if ([[obj1 objectForKey:@"sortorder"] intValue] < [[obj2 objectForKey:@"sortorder"] intValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
};

+ (NSArray *) returnSortedArrayByAlpha:(NSArray*) inputArray whichField:(NSString*) whichField {

    NSArray * sortedArray = [inputArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:sortBlock];
    return  sortedArray;
}
```

Comment: Can you add code for that with the array and dict I'm looking for? something like [array sortedArrayUsingComporator...] which comporator function?

Answer (score 0):

You might have a fundamental misunderstanding here.  `NSDictionary` and `NSSet` objects are always unsorted.

Only `NSArray` and `NSOrderedSet` objects are sorted.

What you probably want to do is create a third object, an NSArray and populate it with whatever keys you want.

Then if you iterate through the NSArray, you can access the dictionary object in order of the sorted array.

Comment: I edited my question. I don't know how to iterate only some objects in that dictionary